# unsigned char array from int array in python

Tags: python, c, int, type-conversion, wiringpi

I try to define a new character (a capital german umlaut "Ä") on my 2004 lcd on a raspberry pi using [wiringPi's `lcdCharDef()`](http://wiringpi.com/dev-lib/lcd-library/)

This is my code

```
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi

# Ä
cap_umlaut_a = [
    int('0b01010', 2),
    int('0b00100', 2),
    int('0b01010', 2),
    int('0b10001', 2),
    int('0b11111', 2),
    int('0b10001', 2),
    int('0b10001', 2),
    int('0b00000', 2)
]

print(cap_umlaut_a) # [10, 4, 10, 17, 31, 17, 17, 0]

wiringpi.lcdCharDef(lcd_handle, 0, cap_umlaut_a)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> TypeError: in method 'lcdCharDef', argument 3 of type 'unsigned char [8]'

I expected these `ints` to be the same as `unsigned chars`

**[edit]**
In a different part of the code I use `ord(char)` to convert only one character to an unsigned int. Can this lead to the correct anser?

How can I cast/convert the array to a type that can be accepted?

P.S. (Note that (as far as I understand it) the python wiringPi library simply wraps the C functions of wiringPi)

**[edit]**
I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi2-Python/issues/20

Comment: you mean something like `wiringpi.lcdCharDef(self.lcd_handle, 0, array.array('B',cap_umlaut_a))`? Sorry, that gives me the same error...

Comment: Have you tried using chr() or byte() instead of int()?  Also, you will need to join them together into a string (python 2) or byte string (python 3) and then decode() them into the Unicode you want.  But why not just use the Unicode \Uxxxxx definition?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I think the Unicode would not work, as I have to define the pixels of the new character myself (the Hitachi HD44780U LCDs are not very smart - they don't know capital umlauts themselves). Or did I get you wrong? However, `chr()` did not work and `byte()` is not a built-in type in python

Comment: chr() doesn't take a string, but it would take your actual number...

Comment: Maybe it takes a bytestring. can you try `wiringpi.lcdCharDef(self.lcd_handle, 0, struct.pack('8B', *cap_umlaut_a))`

Comment: Thank you, @PatrickMaupin! I tried `chr(int('0b01010', 2))` (also with the other `ints`. However, I got the same error message :(

Comment: Thank you @WorldSEnder. Same error, regretfully... In a different part of the program I use `ord(char)` - for only one character. Does this maybe help?

Comment: Did you join() them into a string?  `"".join(cap_umlaut_a)`

Comment: @PatrickMaupin yes. this gives a different error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Is it Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Python 3 - sorry I didn't mention that earlier...

Comment: according to [the source](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/644529) and [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/644529) it should work with a byte-string.

Comment: I think that error occurs when you do the conversion -- you have to join() chr().  In other words, if you define a list of integers like you did above, you should then be able to do `cap_umlaut_a = ''.join(chr(x) for x in cap_umlaut_a)` as a separate step.  See if that works.

Comment: My mistake previously -- it's bytes, not byte.  Try getting your list of bytes like you do above ([int(),...]) and then try this `cap_umlaut_a = b''.join(bytes(x) for x in cap_umlaut_a)`

Comment: Oops, the source is here: https://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python/blob/7e1c18325ba7d56fe4a0a77a280e444c5e8a3c10/wiringpi_wrap.c#L5393

Comment: so you both think I need a byte string... hmmm I tried what you suggested, @PatrickMaupin. `print(cap_umlaut_a)` now gives b'\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x0' however, I still get the same TypeError... :(

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of research and found the source of the relevant python binding [at this github repo](https://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python/blob/7e1c18325ba7d56fe4a0a77a280e444c5e8a3c10/wiringpi_wrap.c#L5393).

The line in question is

```c
res3 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj2, &argp3,SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char, 0 | 0 );
```

as you can see, you have to pass in the python equivalent of a pointer to unsigned char.  According to [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/644529), the equivalent is a byte-string. This means that the correct call would be

```py
import struct
wiringpi.lcdCharDef(lcd_handle, 0, struct.pack('8B', *cap_umlaut_a))
```

which should be equivalent to

```py
wiringpi.lcdCharDef(lcd_handle, 0, b'\x0A\x04\x0A\x11\x1F\x11\x11\x00')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really appreciate that! I just tried it. `wiringpi.lcdCharDef(self.lcd_handle, 0, b'\x0A\x04\x0A\x11\x1F\x11\x11\x0')` gives an error "ValueError: invalid \x escape" and `wiringpi.lcdCharDef(lcd_handle, 0, struct.pack('8B', *cap_umlaut_a))` gives "struct.error: pack requires exactly 8 arguments"

Comment: I fixed the first error, but I *can't* reproduce the second one (with the definitions from your question)

Comment: hm. thanks for fixing the first one - I've seen it myself now :) now I also get the TypeError here... Maybe there is something else wrong in my code. I will try to make a running minimal example tomorrow and either post it or accept your answer, if I can locate the mistake.

Comment: ... well, who needs sleep anyway. I just created the minimal example. Still get the same error. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0fd82d376cd22763faf1

Comment: @speendo, can you try with a normal string instead of a byte string? :<

Comment: I just tried `wiringpi.lcdCharDef(lcd_handle, 0, 'AAAAAAAA')`. Same result. I think I'll ask the maintainer on github...

Comment: I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi2-Python/issues/20